# Is it safe to use a remote etc/hosts file?

Tags: linux, hosts

We have 7-8 PCs that have IP addresses in the hosts file. Our issue is that these addresses can change (because we are tied in to corporate DHCP and have no control over this).

What I am thinking of doing is pointing all the PCs to a remote hosts file on one PC (as a symbolic link). Then we only have to update the hosts file on one PC when things change.

Is there anything wrong with this idea?
Is there a better solution? (maybe hosts file can "pull in a second file remotely?)

Comment: Can't you just use your actual DHCP to propagate the proper names? Are there that many different ones for the same IP(s)?

Comment: I am not sure how I could do that. I should mentioned that the "corporate" network is all windows based. Our boxes are all linux (if that makes a difference)

Comment: Check the DHCP's documentation. If the DHCP server is a Windows host, then you should be able to modify the server's `hosts` file and be fine.

Comment: Hi There, the problem I have is that this is the corporate server :( ... we have no access to that. So this is why I am looking some wacky alternatives :o

Comment: Ah, OK. So these don't have any NetBIOS names you could use either? Maybe talk to your IT regarding this issue?

Comment: I hate to bad-mouth IT depts ... but once you leave the windows world, they generally don't care :( - that is my other issue